# Zoom to spatial coordinate in OpenLayers load

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, zoom

I am working on a project that uses OpenLayers to show shapefiles from the GeoServer and then show them on Google Maps. The only problem is when the page loads, I want to go to the spatial coordinate and zoom to the shapefile that is loaded on map. Is there any way to do this? I want to go to the coordinates around 32 and 50 in zone 39N. Can you help me about this problem?

I tried this code:

```
var dataExtent = states.getDataExtent();
map.zoomToExtent(dataExtent);
```

But it does not work, where is my mistake?

This is the result:

`h++p://173.244.165.194/`

It loads many maps of world.  I have to zoom to go to my location :(
Here is exact place that I want to zoom when page loads:

```
http://173.244.165.194/?zoom=12&lat=31.62211&lon=51.48708&layers=B00T
```

Comment: first, your map must be in the same projection than your layer

Comment: I set maps projection and it places on right location.I just want to load a cordinate on start

Answer (score 1):

its difficult to know what is going wrong without all your code.

If you dont define a map size, you can try to do it before calling map.zoomToExtent()

```
map.size = new OpenLayers.Size(1125,745);
```

Comment: Thanks..What does map.size do?its parameters are cordinates?

Comment: no the parameters are just the widh and heigh of the map in pixel (int). I had problem with zoomToExtent() in some projects when the size was not defined.

Comment: I set the size to full screen.I used the sample template in openlayers website and changed it into what I needed ,Anyway I'll try your suggestion and let you know the results,Thank you very much